# A sub-request on a <link>

Tags: php, html, css

When `<img src="test.php" alt="">` a PHP script will be executed. Why can't I do the same with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.php">
```

?

Comment: You can. Are you sending the right headers?

Comment: Are you sure that the browser didn't cache the resource?

Comment: Why are you thinking you can't?

Answer (score 1):

You can.  Just make sure you set the header to text/css at the top of the php file, before you send any output.  Also you probably want to set some caching on it, my preference is for far-futures and then to change the filename if/when I change the css.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8");    //make the browser see this as a valid CSS file
header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000");  //long in the future for requestless caching
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be header, include this header on the test.php script

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/css');

  /*your css below*/
?>
```

I hope it may solve your issue